# How to consume/get the real error stack from the sourcemap (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project in production generated with webpack and I am trying to get the full stack on an error by knowing the url of my script, url of the sourcemap, line, col...

Is that possible?

Comment: If you can't reproduce this in a dev-env, you have a hard time to get this informations. For the future i recommend something like bugsnag or sentryio to track errors in prod-envs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on which tool you are using to monitor the errors (which you haven't specified).

New Relic supports uploading source maps, which "un-minify" error stack traces.

More info here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/browser-pro-features/upload-source-maps-api/

Comment: So, if they can get the stack trace, from my source-map and my minified script. It means there is a way to do it. How I can do it without using new relic?